# Composing two functions in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to make a Scheme function which takes the functions f(x) and g(x) and combines them into f(g(x)) 
Here's the attempt to my solution.
define(combine R T)(lambda(x) (R(T(x)))
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're missing the opening paren/round bracket before define. also x shouldn't be in parens `(R(T x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> define(combine R T)(lambda(x) (R(T(x)))
>
> What am I doing wrong?

You have `(` in the wrong place

```
(define (compose f g)
  (λ (x) (f (g x))))
```